# Eagerly loading entities in Linq2Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, eager-loading

I’m trying to eagerly load an entity and its related properties (basic one to many) using the LoadWith and AssociateWith DataLoadOptions.  However, after looking at the generated SQL I noticed that the statements generated by LoadWith are all Left Outer Joins.

So the code below generates all left outer joins to fetch the data of the associated properties.  Why is that?  And is there any way to get LoadWith to generate inner joins instead.  I know I can do this with a simple “Linq join”, however, I like how clean and simple the LoadWith syntax is.  Thanks in advance

```
dataLoadOptions.LoadWith(Of TCustomer)(Function(c) c.Orders)
dataLoadOptions.LoadWith(Of TOrder)(Function(o) o.Products)
dataLoadOptions.LoadWith(Of TProduct)(Function(p) p.ProductTranslations)
dataLoadOptions.AssociateWith(Of TProduct)(Function(c) c.ProductTranslations.Where(Function(t) t.Language = "En"))
```

Comment: Why do you want inner joins. It seems pretty reasonable that LINQ to SQL generates outer joins, because with inner joins a customer that has no orders would not be fetched. Perhaps you should explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have been more clear.  What I want is to bring back all Customer's orders for which an English product translation exists.  As far as the outer joins, I think Linq should allow me to explicitly construct either an outer or inner join.  Sorry If this is still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all Customer's orders for which an English product translation exists

```
dataLoadOptions.AssociateWith<TCustomer>(c => c.Orders
  .Where(o => o.Products
      .SelectMany(p => p.ProductTranslations)
      .Any(pt => pt.Language == "En")
  )
);
```